# Circle animation lags

Tags: ios, swift, animation, geometry

I am working on a circle animation in iOS which looks like this:

[Circle animation video link](https://youtu.be/vr_VI_1tzig)

In this animation when circle repeats the animation, it lags in between of animation. I want to make this animation smooth.

I am using a clear view, in which I am adding a circle shape layer. Below is the code for creating circle shape layer:

```
//Create circle shape layer
func setupCircle(frame: CGRect, strokeColor: CGColor)->CAShapeLayer {

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.height/2, y: frame.size.height/2), radius: CGFloat((frame.size.height/2)-25), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

    return shapeLayer
}
```

Below is the code for animating circle shape layer:

```
    //Add animation to circle layer
    func getAnimationForCircle(frame: CGRect) -> CAAnimation {

        let newPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.height/2, y: frame.size.height/2), radius: CGFloat((frame.size.height/2)+25), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        let pathAnim = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "path")
        pathAnim.toValue = newPath.cgPath

        let alphaAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
        alphaAnimation.fromValue = 0.75
        alphaAnimation.toValue = 0.0

        let combinedAnim = CAAnimationGroup.init()
        combinedAnim.animations = [pathAnim, alphaAnimation]
        combinedAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        combinedAnim.repeatCount = .infinity
//        combinedAnim.speed = 0.2
        combinedAnim.duration = 1.0
        combinedAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth

        return combinedAnim
    }
```

How can I make this animation smooth without any lag?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: so I cannot tell the lag you are speaking of cause the video is short and I cannot tell if youtube is buffering or if there is a pause. am I seeing that right.  Is that the smoothness you are having an issue with or is it the alpha jumping back to 1 suddenly that you are trying to fix.  Are you doing anything else on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, there is a pause in animation, I want to remove that pause itself.

Comment: k just ran it myself and I am not seeing the pause. Are you doing anything else that might be slowing it down

Comment: I am fetching results from the server, but it is happing in the background not on the main thread.

Comment: You might trying watching the CPU Report screen in Xcode while running the app to see if there's a CPU spike on the main thread around the time of the animation stutter. If so, you can then profile in Instruments to pinpoint what's causing the spike. I seems likely that there may be some processing going on in the main thread after the results from the server query are received.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would be make the individual animations the same duration as the group so that they match in the repeat count and duration.  I modified the opacity to have a keyframe.  The duration difference may have been causing your stutter or lag.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let shapeLayer = self.setupCircle(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/2, height: self.view.bounds.width/2), strokeColor: UIColor.blue.cgColor)

        let sub = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width/2, height: self.view.bounds.width/2))
        shapeLayer.frame = sub.bounds
        sub.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        sub.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(sub)


        let anim = self.getAnimationForCircle(frame: shapeLayer.frame)
        shapeLayer.add(anim, forKey: nil)
    }



    //Create circle shape layer
    func setupCircle(frame: CGRect, strokeColor: CGColor)->CAShapeLayer {

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.height/2, y: frame.size.height/2), radius: CGFloat((frame.size.height/2)-25), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        //change the fill color
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        //you can change the stroke color
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = strokeColor
        //you can change the line width
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0

        return shapeLayer
    }

    //Add animation to circle layer
    func getAnimationForCircle(frame: CGRect) -> CAAnimation {

        let newPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.height/2, y: frame.size.height/2), radius: CGFloat((frame.size.height/2)+25), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        let pathAnim = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "path")
        pathAnim.toValue = newPath.cgPath
        pathAnim.duration = 1.0

        let alphaAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
        alphaAnimation.values = [0,0.75,0,0]
        alphaAnimation.keyTimes = [0,0.1,0.87,1]
        alphaAnimation.duration = 1.0

        let combinedAnim = CAAnimationGroup.init()
        combinedAnim.animations = [pathAnim, alphaAnimation]
        combinedAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        combinedAnim.repeatCount = .infinity

        combinedAnim.duration = 1.0
        combinedAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth

        return combinedAnim
    }

}
```